# RPC CALL WITHOUT HAVING LAMPORTS

Tags: solana-program, rpc, js, client

So, I want to know if I make an RPC call from my client-side and my account has 0 balance. Does the RPC call go till the validator and get rejected or does the RPC call itself reject the program?

Answer (score 2):

Most `RPC` calls are `read` hence you don't even sign them, so the `RPC` doesn't even know if you have `lamports` or not.

I think it's only relevant for:

https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#sendTransaction

https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#sendRawTransaction

Answer (score 1):

Client-side is inherently unsafe. For this reason the check will always happen on the validator side. On the client side it can only happen as convenience to avoid sending a transaction to the validator that is guaranteed to fail anyway, but the validator will always check it.

Also you have to watch what RPC call you are doing. If you are only reading data - no transaction will execute and hence lamports do not matter.

If you are sending a transaction to add/mutate some data on chain - you will have to pay transaction costs/rent as required for such a transaction and the validator will check that you have enough to cover it.